# How to pass several images through one SeparableConv2D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have several images as input. I know I can use 3D convolutional layers, but I don't want to do it. Instead I want to find the patterns in the 2 dimentions of images.

I mean each image should be passed through `SeparableConv2D`, like that:

```py
# this code raises an error ValueError: Input 0 of layer <name> is 
# incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5.
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=(16, 128, 128, 1)),
    SeparableConv2D(32, 3),
    GlobalAvgPool3D(),
])
```

I know, I can use here `Conv3D` as `Conv2D`:

```py
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=(16, 128, 128, 1)),
    Conv3D(32, [1, 3, 3]),
    GlobalAvgPool3D(),
])
```

But I need exactly `SeparableConv2D`.

Maybe I can do it through the custom layer or something else? I just can't even imagine a solution.

---

P.S. Each input contains several images.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure your input shape should be 4D.As `SeparableConv2D` expects input of shape 4D tensor with shape: `(batch_size, channels, rows, cols)` if data_format='channels_first' or 4D tensor with shape: `(batch_size, rows, cols, channels)` if data_format='channels_last'.

**Working example**

```
import tensorflow as tf
input_shape = (16, 128, 128, 1)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
y = tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D( 2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
print(y.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(16, 126, 126, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have images such as frames of video , and they are connected to each other in somehow
you can loop over the conv2d and pass them one by one

check this example from [my git repo](https://github.com/mamonraab/violance-detection-in-video-with-pytroch) for video action recognition

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        num_classes = 1
        dr_rate= 0.2
        pretrained = True
        rnn_hidden_size = 30
        rnn_num_layers = 2
        #get a pretrained vgg19 model ( taking only the cnn layers and fine tun them)
        baseModel = models.vgg19(pretrained=pretrained).features  
        i = 0
        for child in baseModel.children():
            if i < 28:
                for param in child.parameters():
                    param.requires_grad = False
            else:
                for param in child.parameters():
                    param.requires_grad = True
            i +=1

        num_features = 12800
        self.baseModel = baseModel
        self.dropout= nn.Dropout(dr_rate)
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(num_features, rnn_hidden_size, rnn_num_layers , batch_first=True)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(30, 256)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, num_classes)
    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size, time_steps, C, H, W = x.size()
        # reshape input  to be (batch_size * timesteps, input_size)
        x = x.contiguous().view(batch_size * time_steps, C, H, W)
        x = self.baseModel(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        #make output as  ( samples, timesteps, output_size)
        x = x.contiguous().view(batch_size , time_steps , x.size(-1))
        x , (hn, cn) = self.rnn(x)
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x[:, -1, :])) # get output of the last  lstm not full sequence
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

the main idea is in this block we distribute  each frame or image to the conv net and than we reshape or even feed its to new network

```
# reshape input  to be (batch_size * timesteps, input_size)
 x = x.contiguous().view(batch_size * time_steps, C, H, W)
 # feed to the pre-trained conv model
 x = self.baseModel(x)
 # flatten the output
 x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
 # make the new correct shape (batch_size , timesteps , output_size)
 x = x.contiguous().view(batch_size , time_steps , x.size(-1))  # this x is now ready to be entred or feed into lstm layer
```